# Microservice java property not set in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, docker, properties

I have the following line in micros1-mvc microservice application.properties: `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_SERVER}`

I execute the microservice inside the container with:

```
sudo docker run -p 8081:8081 --network mynetw --env JAVA_OPTS="-DEUREKA_SERVER=http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka" micros1-mvc
```

And when the microservice tries to connect with Eureka it says:

> overyClient    :
> DiscoveryClient_SERVICEASERVICE/1754e70517a8:serviceaservice:8081 -
> was unable to refresh its cache! This periodic background refresh will
> be retried in 30 seconds. status = **There is no known eureka server;
> cluster server list is empty** stacktrace =
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: There is no
> known eureka server; cluster server list is empty     at
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:108)
> at
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
> at
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
> at
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
> at
> com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
> at
> com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1101)
> at
> com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1014)
> at
> com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1531)

It looks like the microservice properties file doesn't receive the specified value in docker execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I came across the fact that JAVA_OPTS are very specific to Catalina (Tomcat). Looking in the bin folder of a tomcat install you'll find a shell script that handles passing JAVA_OPTS into the exec lines.

A Dockerfile like:
`FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine`
`VOLUME /tmp`
`ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar`
`COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar`
`ENTRYPOINT ["java","${JAVA_OPTS}","-jar","/app.jar"]`

With:
`docker run -p 9000:9000 -e JAVA_OPTS=-Dserver.port=9000 myorg/myapp`

Fails. This fails because the ${} substitution requires a shell. The exec form does not use a shell to launch the process, so the options are not applied. You can get around that by moving the entry point to a script or by explicitly creating a shell in the entry point. The following example shows how to create a shell in the entry point:
`ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app.jar"]`

You can then launch this app by running the following command:
`docker run -p 8080:8080 -e "JAVA_OPTS=-Ddebug -Xmx128m" myorg/myapp`